# How to use input:nth-of-type(n) for selecting an input tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to apply a style only to a specific input tag using `E:input:nth-of-type(n)`.

Please look at his jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nLK2w/3/

Could you point me out what is wrong here? Would make sense use    `E:nth-of-type(n)` instead?

```
 <div class="snippet-navsetupfieldschosen" style="">
     <h1>xxx</h1><ul>
        <li>
            <input id="regionselection1" type="text" readonly="" name="regionselection1" data-href="regionselection1" class="focusable">
            </li>
        <li>
            <input id="regionselection2" type="text" readonly="" name="regionselection2" data-href="regionselection2" class="focusable">
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>



.snippet-navsetupfieldschosen ul li input:nth-of-type(1) {
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the first `input` you want, but the first `<li>`. Every `input` ís the first child of every `<li>`, so your code effects every input you have in your html.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/nLK2w/4/

Answer (score 2):

To make sure, in your case, that your first input gets selected with the styles that you want, you need to make the `li` element to have a `:first-child` to ensure that it understands that the first child of li with the input having `:nth-of-type(1)` (for now it is one) should get selected.

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nLK2w/6/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
.snippet-navsetupfieldschosen ul li:first-child input:nth-of-type(1) {
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    background:red;
}
```

Hope this helps.